# Conversion to integer isn't executing?

Tags: ruby

i have this code :

```
#require_relative '../lib/hackex/net/typhoeus'
require_relative '../lib/hackex'
require 'rubygems'
require 'faker'

    print "how many farms do you want : "
    choice = gets.chomp
    choice.to_i
    check = choice.is_a?(Integer)
    puts check
    if choice > 250
    puts "Error! you cannot make more than 250 farms at once"
    elsif choice < 250
    puts "Error! you have to make at least one farm..."
    elsif choice.is_a?(Integer) == false
    puts "Error, something went wrong !"
    else
    puts "making #{choice} acounts ! ! !"
    cnt = 1
            while choice>cnt
            gen = Faker::Name.first_name + Faker::Name.last_name
            path=("created1.txt")
            email = gen+'@gmail.com'
            password = Faker::Internet.password(8)
            username = gen.to_s+'/>'
            puts HackEx::Request.Do(http,HackEx::Request.CreateUser(username, email, password, facebook_id = nil))
            cnt +=1
            open(path, 'a') { |f|
                    f << "#{email};"
                    f << "#{password}"
                    f << "\n"
                    }
                puts "Account created!"
                puts "#{choice - cnt} accounts remaining!"
            end
            end
```

i am trying to determing if the choice is an integer... i did the .to_i on choice, but it returns false, meaning its not an integer, its a string, why isnt it switching ?
ps : i do not get any errors, and the rest of the code works fine, except for the if part

Comment: Please use English punctuation when you write in English.

Answer (score 3):

`choice.to_i` *returns* an integer, but does not change `choice`. If you want `choice` to be changed to the integral value of the old `choice`, you need to reassign it explicitly:

```
choice = choice.to_i
```

Comment: You can also do that `choice.to_i!` for more simplicity, which guarantees an overwrite of the variable. Most people don't like to use `!` in this way, though.

Comment: @c650: No, you cannot. Such a method does not exist, and is not possible - a method cannot change the object's class membership. `String#gsub!` changes a `String`, it does not create a new object. The hypothetical `String#to_i!` would have to magically turn a `String` object into a `Fixnum`.

Comment: @Amadan: wow, in the 6 months I've used this language I'd always thought that any reassignment method that returns a mutated version of the object it's called upon had the `!` option. Of course, doing so was never really good practice imo so I never realized this.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [doc of String::to_i](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-to_i), emphasis is mine

> ### to_i(base=10) → integer
>
> **Returns** the result of interpreting leading characters in str as an
>   integer base base (between 2 and 36).

So you have to assign the return to something, or itself:

```
choice = choice.to_i
```